# How do I choose between two forms of a word like "deprivation" and "depriving"?

Tags: word-choice

> In a land haunted by death when ‘life’ itself is at stake why am I talking about schools and education? The beauty of education is that it has been imparted in the times of ‘wars’ and ‘calamities’, in sheds, barracks, prisons and concentration camps. Agreed, Kashmir is a conflict zone and imparting education to children here is a Herculean task-but is **deprivation** an answer?

Is *deprivation* a correct usage here or should it be *depriving*?

Comment: Please provide the whole context. Both versions could be correct, and you have provided nothing to help distinguish between them. You could also edit into your question why you think the choice is available: why do you think *depriving* might fit into your sentence? Why might *deprivation* fit?

Comment: It has been edited...

Comment: It's not a hyphen, it's a dash, which is sort of a strong comma. Please don't ask two questions at once. I'll edit this one.

Comment: OK... I've undone my unilateral vote, although others may still feel that you should say why you think *depriving* would fit here.

Comment: I think this question would be a better fit, and attract more helpful answers, on our sister site, [ELL.se].  If you haven't checked them out yet, you should.

Comment: Your sentence is unclear. That *deprivation* is just hanging in the middle of nowhere. And that doesn't change if you change that word to *depriving*. Deprivation of whom from what? You will need to reframe the whole sentence.

Comment: It's been reframed.

Comment: Thanks for reframing Faizan. I've also made a minor edit to make the quote clearer. But the question would still be better placed and get more helpful answers on [ELL.se]. There are several more conspicuous issues than "deprivation", and the teachers over there will help you understand what features of your native language account for these kinds of errors, and what the English rules are that govern them.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is deprivation an answer to what? As the passage stands it almost sounds like it is a beautiful thing to impart education while there is a war going on. I'm relatively sure you don't mean this. I imagine you mean that the beauty of education is that it can be imparted despite wars, not because of them??
It occurs to me on rereading that you might mean: Is forgoing education the answer? (in a rhetorical sense, where the obvious answer should be 'no'.)

Comment: You need parallelism: Imparting education to x is y and how would depriving them of it be an answer? [I am helping you as this is about children and therefore matters, charitably speaking].

Comment: It should really be neither. Both words are clumsy here. Neither one works well on its own in that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I think **deprivation** is correct, which means the state of being deprived. If you choose **depriving** you should continue the sentense because depriving means the act of depriving someone from something, and the arguments of predicate must be mentioned. 
From context, deprivation makes sense very well.

Comment: I don't understand: noun an noun... deprivation an answer... please elaborate it more clearly.